# How to fix SUPEE-9652 Resolve Zend Framework Security Issue

Tags: security, magento-1.9, patch

I Install Security patch in magento 1.9.3.1 and i got error like:

**Community Edition 1.9.3.2 and SUPEE-9652 Resolve Zend Framework Security Issue – 2/7/2017**

How do i fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

To protect your site from this vulnerability, you should immediately check your mail sending settings. Go to the system settings used to control the “Reply to” address for emails sent from your Magento store:

Magento 1: System-> Configuration-> Advanced-> System-> Mail Sending Settings-> Set Return-Path

Magento 2: Stores-> Configuration-> Advanced-> System-> Mail Sending Settings-> Set Return-Path

If “Set Return-Path” is set to “Yes,” and your server uses Send mail, then your store is vulnerable to this exploit.

Comment: I already tried this but this not solved my issue. @Abhinav Kumar Singh

Comment: After implementing security patch 9652  if you are getting security patch message then you can ignore it. Please check these links. It may also help you-

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-9652
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158666/securitypatch-9652-possible-problems-after-supee-9652-applied

Comment: yes but when i see my site in magereport.com than its shows like this:-Security patch 9652 unknown
Patch SUPEE-9652 prevents attackers from executing PHP code through a bug in the Zend Framework's Sendmail adapter. Released Feb 6th, 2017. This patch cannot be detected from the outside, without hacking your shop. More about this specific patch and how we detect it.
We were unable to conclusively check your shop. The check might have been blocked by other emergency measures you, or your provider, have taken.